# Using the browser to call a server via Salesforce

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a request from my client, for security issue, the client doesn't want Salesforce to make a direct call to their webservice. My question, is how can I use the browser to make the call to the client'server, initiating the action in Salesforce. 
I'm thinking that a JavaScript can do it, is someone already done this? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: From what context? A Visualforce page? A Lightning component? Something else?

Comment: VisualForce, no lightening

Answer (score 3):

Doing callout in Javascript is riskier than Salesforce doing a callout.

1. It will be browser and location based so callout can happen from diffrent IP addresses(Nightmare)
2. It can be easily tracked hacked modified in JS
3. If its OAUTH then you have to expose credentials and endpoint in javascript which again can be easily read with native browser Inspect or developer tools.

That being said, if you still wanna do it, you can.

> By default, you can’t make calls to third-party APIs from client-side
>   code. Add a remote site as a CSP Trusted Site to allow client-side
>   component code to load assets from and make API requests to that
>   site’s domain. The Lightning Component framework uses Content Security
>   Policy (CSP), which is a W3C standard, to control the source of
>   content that can be loaded on a page. Lightning apps are served from a
>   different domain than Salesforce APIs, and the default CSP policy
>   doesn’t allow API calls from JavaScript code. You change the policy,
>   and the content of the CSP header, by adding CSP Trusted Sites.

Sample code to do callout:

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
console.log(Http.responseText)
}
```

Src: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa

http://sfdcode.com/integration/making-third-party-API-calls-from-lightning-components/

Comment: One thing about that is that it might be useful to call the service from the browser if it's only going to be used within the company's intranet. That way, they can whitelist by IP. In that sense, I've seen some customers include private services via a simple iframe that checks the original IP.

Comment: Aha, makes sense to call endpoint which are not publicly available... Never thought about it. Thanks @Aidan

Comment: It will be used in company's intranet, and there is already a whitelist by IP. Thank you very much for your help. @Aidin ,Pranay